# A variety of rsync commands in a cron script to sync Ubuntu & Mac home directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, rsync, osx-yosemite

I have a Thinkpad running Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) which is on a wired network and a Mac running Yosemite on wireless, in a different subnet. They're both work machines. I also have a 1TB encrypted USB external Lenovo disk. I have created the following script to run from cron from the Thinkpad to sync the hidden folders in /home/greg with the external drive (connected to the TP), providing it's mounted to the right dir. Then it should sync the remaining, non-hidden) content of /home/greg and perhaps select customised parts of /etc. Once that's done, it should do something similar for the Mac, keeping the hidden files separate but doing a union of the content. My first rsync is meant to only include the hidden files (.*/) in /home/greg and the second rsync is meant to grab everything that's not hidden in that directory. The following is a work in progress.

```
#!/bin/bash
#source
LOCALHOME="/home/greg/"

#target disk
DRIVEBYIDPATH="/dev/disk/by-id"
DRIVEID="disk ID here"
DRIVE=$DRIVEBYIDPATH/$DRIVEID

#mounted target directories
DRIVEMOUNTPOINT="/media/Secure-BU-drive"
THINKPADHIDDENFILES="/TPdot"
MACHIDDENFILES="/MACdot"
BACKUPDIR="/homeBU"

#if test -a $DRIVE ;then echo "-a $?";fi

# Check to see if the drive is showing up in /dev/disk/by-id
function drivePresent {
    if test -e $DRIVE
    then    echo "$DRIVE IS PRESENT!"
        driveMounted
    else
        echo "$DRIVE is NOT PRESENT!"
    fi
}

# Check to see if drive is mounted where expected by rsync and if not mount it
function driveMounted {
    mountpoint -q  $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]
    then
        syncLocal #make sure local has completed before remote starts
#temp disabled  syncRemote
    else
        echo "drive $DRIVEID is PRESENT but NOT MOUNTED. Mounting $DRIVE on $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT"
        mount $DRIVE $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT
        if [ $? == 0 ]
        then
          driveMounted
          #could add a counter + while/if to limit the retries to say 5?
        fi # check mount worked, then re-test until true, at which point the test will follow the other path
    fi
}

# Archive THINKPAD to USB encrypted drive
function syncLocal { 
    echo "drive $DRIVEID is PRESENT and MOUNTED on $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT- now do rsync"
    #rsync for all the Linux application specific files (hidden directories)
    rsync -ar --delete --update $LOCALHOME/.* $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT/$BACKUPDIR/$THINKPADHIDDENFILES  
    #rsync for all the content (non-hidden directories)
    rsync -ar --delete --exclude-from ./excludeFromRsync.txt $LOCALHOME $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT/$BACKUPDIR 
    #rsync for Linux /etc dir (includes some custom scripts and cron jobs)
    #rsync
}

# Sync MAC to USB encrypted drive
function syncRemote { # Sync Mac to USB encrypted drive
    echo "drive $DRIVEID is PRESENT and MOUNTED on $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT- now do rsync"
    #rsync for all the Mac application specific files (hidden directories)
    rsync -h --progress --stats -r -tgo -p -l -D --update /home/greg/ /media/Secure-BU-drive/
    #rsync for all the content (non-hidden directories)
    rsync -av --delete --exclude-from ./excludeFromRsync.txt $LOCALHOME $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT/$BACKUPDIR
    #rsync for Mac /etc dir (includes some custom scripts and cron jobs)
    rsync
}

#This is the program starting
drivePresent
```

The content of the exclude file mentioned in the second rsync in syncLocal is (nb syncRemote is disabled for the moment):

```
.cache/
/Downloads/
.macromedia/
.kde/cache-North/
.kde/socket-North/
.kde/tmp-North/
.recently-used
.local/share/trash
**/*tmp*/
**/*cache*/
**/*Cache*/
**~
/mnt/*/**
/media/*/**
**/lost+found*/
/var/**
/proc/**
/dev/**
/sys/**
**/*Trash*/
**/*trash*/
**/.gvfs/
/Documents/RTC*
.*
```

My problem is that the first local rsync that's meant to be capturing ONLY the /home/greg/.* files seems to have captured everything or possible has failed silently and allowed the second local rsync to run but without excluding the /home/greg/.* files?
I know I've added a load of possibly irrelevant context but I thought it might help set my expectations for the related rsyncs. Sorry if I've gone overboard.

Thanks in advance
Greg

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful with `.*` as it will pull in `.` and `..`. So that's your first rsync line:

```
  rsync -ar --delete --update $LOCALHOME/.*  $DRIVEMOUNTPOINT/$BACKUPDIR/$THINKPADHIDDENFILES
```

The shell expand `*` and so rsync sees `.` and `..` and it will go full-recursive on those two!

I wonder if this might help: `--exclude . --exclude ..` Well, I'm sure you know about using `-vn` to help you debug rsync issues.